# Переписать элементы массива. C#

Tags: c#, массивы, .net

Почему при добавлении элемента в методе InsertElement() индекс выходит за границы?

```
namespace CSRIerarchy
{
  class Container
  {
    public static Sofa[] product={};

    public Container()
    {

    }

    public static void InsertElement(Sofa value)
    {

        Sofa[] tmp = new Sofa[product.Length+1];
        for (int i = 0; i <product.Length; i++)
        {
            tmp[i] = product[i];
        }
        product = tmp;
        product[product.Length+1] = value; // Конкретно здесь ошибка.
    }
    public static void DeleteElement( int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= product.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Индекс за пределами массива");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            var newArray = new Sofa[product.Length - 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < product.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i < index)
                {
                    newArray[i] = product[i];
                }
                else if (i > index)
                {
                    newArray[i - 1] = product[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void SortArray()
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Вот вызов метода в Main

```
class Program : Container
{

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Sofa a = new Sofa("CononeSofa",3244.12,"Для гостинной","Красное дерево, сталь,полиэстер",120,150,"Двухместный");
        Sofa b = new Sofa("CononeSofa", 3244.12, "Для гостинной", "Красное дерево, сталь,полиэстер", 120, 150, "Двухместный");
        Sofa c = new Sofa("CononeSofa", 3244.12, "Для гостинной", "Красное дерево, сталь,полиэстер", 120, 150, "Двухместный");
        InsertElement(a);
        //DeleteElement(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Индекс последнего элемента = `(длина - 1)`.

```
public static void InsertElement(Sofa value)
{
  ...
  product[product.Length - 1] = value; // больше нет ошибки
}


public static void DeleteElement( int index)
{
  ...
  product = newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку это не выглядит как учебное задание, вам стоит использовать `List<T>`, который умеет динамически расти.

```
class Container
{
    List<Sofa> product = new List<Sofa>();

    public void InsertElement(Sofa value)
    {
        product.Add(value);
    }

    public static void DeleteElement(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= product.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Индекс за пределами массива");
            return;
        }

        product.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}
```

---

А если это вдруг учебное задание, то перечитайте лекцию.

Comment: По условию задания нельзя использовать коллекции

Comment: @Bigniggaboss: То есть это _учебное_ задание? Тогда немедленно перечитывать учебник. Если вы не сумеете самостоятельно реализовать коллекцию на основе массива, вы в принципе не сможете стать программистом.

Comment: @VladID: Да, это учебное задание. Учту ваш совет